# Liquibase defaulSchema on subselect

Tags: liquibase

I have a table A and an associative table B that has a FK to A.
I need to delete something from A but before I do it I need to delete A from table B.
I don't control the records ids so:

```
- delete:
      tableName: B
      where: COD_A = (SELECT COD_A FROM A WHERE name = 'A_NAME')
- delete:
      tableName: A
      where: name = 'A_NAME'
```

My problem is that the subselect(SELECT COD_A FROM A WHERE name = 'A_NAME') is not getting the schema name from liquibase.defaultSchema.

What can I do to work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was strugling with the wrong property.

```
- delete:
      tableName: B
      where: COD_A = (SELECT COD_A FROM ${database.defaultSchemaName}.A WHERE name = 'A_NAME')
- delete:
      tableName: A
      where: name = 'A_NAME'
```